# How to launch an activity from a dialog?

Tags: android, button, android-activity, dialog, android-intent

Any ideas how to launch an activity and send a value from a dialog button?

Here's what I have at the moment. Tried a number of variations but app crashes when the button is pressed:

```
dialog.setPositiveButton("View Profile", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(context, Profile.class);
        intent.putExtra("profileID",  "8");            
        startActivity(intent);
        dialog.cancel();
        return;
    } 
});
```

Full class:

```
public class PlacesItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Activity aClass;

    public PlacesItemizedOverlay(Context aContext, Drawable marker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(marker));
        context = aContext;
    }

    public void addOverlayItem(OverlayItem item) {
        items.add(item); 
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return (OverlayItem) items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        aClass = new Activity();
        OverlayItem item = (OverlayItem) items.get(index);
        if(item.getTitle() != null)
            {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
            dialog.setPositiveButton("View Profile",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(context, Profile.class);
                    intent.putExtra("profileID",  "8");            
                    aClass.startActivity(intent);
                    dialog.cancel();
                    return;
                } 
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
06-24 10:35:31.253: WARN/dalvikvm(30118): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
06-24 10:35:31.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30118): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 10:35:31.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30118): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-24 10:35:31.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30118):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2901)
06-24 10:35:31.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30118):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3007)
06-24 10:35:31.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30118):     at com.example.android.test.PlacesItemizedOverlay$1.onClick(PlacesItemizedOverlay.java:57)
06-24 10:35:31.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30118):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
06-24 10:35:31.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30118):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-24 10:35:31.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30118):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
06-24 10:35:31.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30118):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
06-24 10:35:31.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30118):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 10:35:31.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30118):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 10:35:31.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30118):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-24 10:35:31.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30118):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-24 10:35:31.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30118):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 10:35:31.293: WARN/ActivityManager(1344):   Force finishing activity com.example.android.test/.SearchActivity
```

Comment: `putExtra()` is the right method to use.  What's the error message in the stack trace?

Comment: You'll have to bare with me Haphazard, Im not used to debugging this yet. I will see if I can find the 'stack trace' and post it. Many thanks.

Comment: Type `adb logcat` into a command window and look for the big error message.

Comment: Firstly, let me apologises if I am being a complete idiot at the moment, I have windows command promt running through eclipse, which I have entered "adb logcat" to which I get 'adb' is not recongnized as an internal or external command. Thank you for helping me with this :)

Comment: You'll have to add `adb` to your Environment Variables.  Or, just call `adb` in the `..\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools` folder

Comment: Got delayed abit, eclipse wouldn't allow me to debug my phone. Sorted it now and will put the results up :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that you have added the  Profile.class in the manifest file like such:

```
 <activity android:name=".Profile" />
```

Comment: Yep, its glued tight in there.

Comment: Try to check that your imports are right, I have ran your code in mine and it is in working order :                                       import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to check it, I appreciate it. Looking at the code it appears good to me, but right now its just not liking the setClass. This think I will post the full file, just incase I'm setting some stupid confliction somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

On the button's onClick, I believe you need to startactivity and set the intent using the new activity and also reference it in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: +1 - I am going to guess the activity isn't in the manifest file.

Comment: What do you mean? You need to reference the all activities in the manifest.

Comment: Sorry guys, the activity is in the manifest file, but I am getting an error now at the setClass which I will update above. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to restructure the code, here is what ended up working:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setTitle(item.getTitle())
.setCancelable(true)
.setPositiveButton("View Details", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Profile.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", item.getSnippet());
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
return true;
```