# Showing a alert dialog box after pressing a button

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am now trying to add a dialog box after I clicked a button. When I click yes it should navigate to another page, if no it will stay on the page.

I tried to add the dialog box into the button but it gives me error. I am unsure about how I should proceed.

Please help.

> MenuActivity.java

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {


private String server = "http://172.16.156.56";
private String sql_table = "orders";
private ListView list;
private String txtOrder, txtMember, txtPrice;
private Button btnAdd;
ArrayList<String> rows;

ListView listView1;
Button btnSubmit;
ArrayList<CustomItem> itemList, selectedList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);


    list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    rows = new ArrayList<String>();


    itemList=new ArrayList<CustomItem>();
    itemList.add(new CustomItem("Fried Rice","description","1","Quantity"));
    itemList.add(new CustomItem("Fried Noodle","description","2","Quantity"));
    itemList.add(new CustomItem("Prawn noodle","description","3","Quantity"));
    itemList.add(new CustomItem("Chicken Rice","description","4","Quantity"));

    int[] prgmImages={R.drawable.friedrice,R.drawable.friednoodle,R.drawable.pnoodle,R.drawable.chickenrice};

    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final CustomLVAdapter customLVAdapter = new CustomLVAdapter(this, itemList,prgmImages);
    listView1.setAdapter(customLVAdapter);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String strMem = extras.getString("Mem");

    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
            selectedList = new ArrayList<CustomItem>();
            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
                CustomItem object = itemList.get(i);
                if (object.isSelected()) {
                    responseText.append(object.getItem() + "," + object.getQty() + ",");//item
                    selectedList.add(object);
                    //calculate price
                    total = total + Integer.parseInt(object.getQty()) * Integer.parseInt(object.getPrice());

                }

            }
            txtOrder = responseText.toString();
            txtPrice = String.valueOf(total);

            Add(responseText.toString(), strMem, String.valueOf(total));

            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ReceiptActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Order",txtOrder);
            i.putExtra("Price",txtPrice);
            i.putExtra("Mem",strMem);
            startActivity(i);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseText + " $" + total,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            confirmdialog();

            SelectAll();
            //store in database

            //go to ReceiptActivity - membership, item, totalprice

        }

        private void confirmdialog() {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MenuActivity.this);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Confirmation");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("Submit order?");

       // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    //whatever you want to do
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReceiptActivity.class);
                }
            });

            // Setting Negative "NO" Button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //cancel the dialog
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

           alertDialog.show();
        }
    });


}

public void Add(final String item, final String membership, final String price)
{
    RequestQueue MyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = server + "/insertorder.php";
    StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    }) {
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            MyData.put("item",item );
            MyData.put("membership",membership );
            MyData.put("price",price );

            return MyData;
        }
    };
    MyRequestQueue.add(MyStringRequest);
    SelectAll();
}
public void SelectAll()
{
    RequestQueue MyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = server + "/fetchorder.php";
    StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray(sql_table);
                rows.clear();
                for(int i=0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                    String order       = jsonChildNode.optString("item").toString();
                    String membership     = jsonChildNode.optString("membership").toString();
                    String price = jsonChildNode.optString("price").toString();

                    rows.add(order + ", " + membership + ", " + price );
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MenuActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rows);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() { //Create an error listener to handle errors appropriately.
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //This code is executed if there is an error.
        }
    });
    MyRequestQueue.add(MyStringRequest);
}

}
```

> Logcat

```
 07-07 16:43:37.425 8696-9039/com.example.android.cardemulation E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash: crash in the same process: Thread-2418
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 493188205 byte allocation with 16777104 free bytes and 142MB until OOM
at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:316)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readString(DiskBasedCache.java:526)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readStringStringMap(DiskBasedCache.java:549)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader.readHeader(DiskBasedCache.java:392)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:155)
at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:84)
07-07 16:43:37.478 8696-8696/com.example.android.cardemulation E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.android.cardemulation.MenuActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{7727bec V.E...... R....... 0,0-1026,543} that was originally added here
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:397)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1112)
at com.example.android.cardemulation.MenuActivity$1.confirmdialog(MenuActivity.java:154)
at com.example.android.cardemulation.MenuActivity$1.onClick(MenuActivity.java:116)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: If you want to start intent in the positive case, why your startActivity(i) is before your confirmDialog()?

Comment: use small sized images, I guess you're using large images and the program is crashing with out of memory exception

Comment: tried putting confirmdialog before startactivity, still getting the same error @ErikMinarini

Comment: Before i added the dialog codes the app was able to run without problems. @SripadRaj

Comment: What is there on `MenuActivity.java:154`?

Comment: dialog.cancel @nerdyGeek

Comment: Does the app crash when you click on the cancel button on the dialog (or on any other event), or does it crash as soon as you launch the app?

Comment: it crashes after i clicked the button @nerdyGeek

Comment: What happens if you say `dialog.dismiss()` instead of `dialog.cancel()`?

Comment: Hi, this question was closed, so I cannot post an answer. However, your problem is that you are calling `confirmdialog();` _after_ calling `startActivity(i)`. You cannot show a dialog outside of an activity context. In your case, your original activity has already exited (since you called `startActivity`) before you show the dialog. Try putting `startActivity(i)` inside `setPositiveButton`'s `onClick()`.

Comment: it still has the same error @nerdyGeek

Comment: Just tried it still has the same error @IshitaSinha

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297687/android-startactivity-from-alertdialog

Comment: @IshitaSinha's link might help as well as these two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725582/how-to-start-activity-only-after-user-clicks-ok-on-alertdialog and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462087/how-to-launch-an-activity-from-a-dialog